# ReportViewer Error with asp.net 3,5

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I'm working visual studio with c#. 
I have a web page and it has a ReportViewer like that:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi" runat="server" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="400px" Width="400px">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="RptCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="odCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi" 
                Name="DsCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi_spCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetData"         
    TypeName="MedulaRaporlari.DataSet.DsCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisiTableAdapters.spCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisiTableAdapter" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And a javascript exception throw when i m starting web page and i cant viewing.

Exceptin is : "ReportViewerHoverButton is undefined". And that exception has thrown for all components of reportviewer.

Answer (score 1):

See this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsreportcontrols/thread/60912c46-3285-4953-8791-ebb338098eb9